# Must my command-line tool be an extension?

Tags: extension

I have made a standalone tool which i start with the command-line to see possible updates in the database to use the actual translations, and a program to compare an existing database with a new installation.
Now you can use the sql-files in the localization-files only with a new installation and i use the new po-files to find possible updates after the normal upgrading in CiviCRM. The translated strings in the database are now never upgraded with new Transifex translations. 
After making the programs i looked how extensions work, but this is not really an extension for users but may be something for the system administrator. 
Are there other kinds of extensions?

Answer (score 1):

If the tool is command-line only, it probably shouldn't be an extension.

If you need to bootstrap CiviCRM from the command line, and you can presume that the [cv](https://github.com/civicrm/cv) tool is in the path, and your tool is PHP-based, you can add the line:

```
eval(`cv php:boot`);
```

or just:

```
cv php:boot --level=classloader
```

This should give you the ability to call CiviCRM classes without creating an extension.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is command-line online, but I think exentions can also be used as a way to distribute the program (with upgrades) if i created a project in Github and manage to add that to the https://civicrm.org/extensions.

Comment: This is an interesting use case!  I would discuss it with the extension team lead, Allen.  His username is @twomice on https://chat.civicrm.org, I would join the `~extensions` channel.